# Install Arch Linux on existing ext4 partition

Tags: arch-linux, partition, system-installation

I have Windows 10 which has three partitions and Ubuntu Mate with two ext4 partitions (one for `/` and one for `/home`) and a swap partition.

How can I install Arch Linux on one of those two ext4 partitions?

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x89a9ee55

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048  204802047  203776000  97,2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        204802048 1852954623 1648152576 785,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1852956670 1953523711  100567042    48G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       1852956672 1899275031   46318360  22,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1899276288 1948102459   48826172  23,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1948104704 1953523711    5419008   2,6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/sdb: 14,5 GiB, 15504900096 bytes, 30283008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0e8688f2

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       16128 30283007 30266880 14,4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb4       12628624 15747075  3118452  1,5G  0 Empty
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/366034/edit) by adding the output of `fdisk -l` , did you need to remove Ubuntu ?

Comment: The user-friendly Arch Linux based distribution is called Manjaro. https://manjaro.org/

Comment: I edited the question with the output of 'fdisk -l' and I also tried Manjaro. It doesn't boot up.

Comment: As GAD3R alluded, is your intention to replace your current Ubuntu installation with Arch, or to install Arch along side Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to replace Ubuntu with Arch and have Arch alongside Windows.